# How to put a model in a scene with another model

Tags: animation

Let's say I make a sword, a shelf and a character. I want to put all three in the same scene with another character and have them fight. I can't figure out how to get models edited and saved into the same scene. Please help. Key words or a English speaking tutorial will help fix the problem. Ty Dwayne Herron.

Comment: You can go to File>Append> then go to your other .blend files with the sword navigate to your object folder and double click on your sword object. It will bring it in to your current file.

Comment: I will try first thing in the morning when I get off work ty